# gruobi: used model.write but cannot find the file

Tags: c++, gurobi

I am using Gurobi with C++ and want to save the Lp as a file.lp. Therefore, I used

```
model.write("model.lp");
model.optimize();
```

This is my output and nor error occurs:

```
Optimize a model with 105 rows, 58 columns and 186 nonzeros
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range    [1e+00, 1e+00]
  Objective range [1e+00, 1e+00]
  Bounds range    [0e+00, 0e+00]
  RHS range       [1e+00, 6e+00]
Presolve removed 105 rows and 58 columns
Presolve time: 0.00s
Presolve: All rows and columns removed
Iteration    Objective       Primal Inf.    Dual Inf.      Time
       0   -0.0000000e+00   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00      0s

Solved in 0 iterations and 0.00 seconds
Optimal objective -0.000000000e+00
obj: -0
Status2
Process finished with exit code 0
```

So there is probably a mistake in my LP, since the optimal solution should not be 0. This is why I want to have a look at the model.lp file. However, I cannot find it. I searched my whole computer. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Have you checked in your current working directory ? The directory from which your program is executed ?

Comment: Yes, it was probably also included when I searched my hole computer. But to be sure, I just checked it again and nothing there :(

Comment: I only see two options left : check that your working directory is not in read only mode; set an absolute path for writing your file.

Comment: thanks, for you help. But it still isn't working. My working directory is not on read only and I tried to save it like this: model.write("user\ClionProjects\modeltest.lp"); but still does not work.

Comment: I just noticed that I not even can write any output file in c++. I tried: ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("user\desktop\example203.txt");                                           myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
myfile.close();
And this also does not work. I am using a mac if this is important

Comment: Hum, on mac you should use slash `/` and not backslash `\ ` to separate directories, then your path should be `/Users/{your-username}/desktop/example203.txt`

Comment: I am not sure about the slash thing. I used slash on myfile.open and I include an additional check myfile.is_open(), which turns out to be false. When I used backslash this was true.  When I used it on model.write (my original problem) I get an error: SIGABRT (Aborted)
But there is no real error message as I am used to. You might notice that I am quite new to C++.

Comment: You should check this about filepath : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29 and note that mac uses unix's style filepath. With `std::fstream` c++ will try to create the file in the specified directory, but if the directory doesn't exists, it will not create it for you. You should open a console and check that your path exists by typing `cd /my/path/to/my/doc`

Comment: Hey I finally got it. You were right!!!. I used slash again and I noticed that I ignored the case sensitivity. So Desktop was written big :/.
Thanks a lot